# How to Flatten ImageMagick image from layer 0 to Canvas?

Tags: image, imagemagick

When I create a layered image in ImageMagick the result PNG has a Layer 0 instead of a being on a Canvas Background. I've used flatten image function but it drags it down to Layer 0 which I believe is a combination of all the flattened images.

How can I flatten this down to Background Canvas?

Comment: Solved it. Alpha has to be turned off. `convert source.png -alpha off destination.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you convert it to jpeg, it will remove all of the layers and flatten the image

```
exec("convert image.png image.jpg");
```

Comment: Cheers but that dosent help if I want to retain the PNG. JPG looses too much quality but I want to retain it here. Any other options to flatten the PNG while remaining it's file type?

Comment: you can actually set the jpg to `-quality 100%`  thats how i create many images at work and we do large photographic printing - up to 40"x120". we ALWAYS print jpeg